# Return null and not null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, query-string

I have two tables, one for customers and another one for nationalities, not all customers table have nationality assigned to them they just Null, and the rest assigned to them their nationality, my problem now that in my select query its return only the customers who have nationality assigned to them and its ignore the null value, i need select query get the null and not null values.

Note: i need this result using inner join.
There are another table with relation with customer table that i cant get from it the user name who created this customer, and always no null value because no customer crested without creator, but for my above issue come customers without nationality assigned to them, and some of them with nationality assigned to them, and i need this both records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Note: i need this result using inner join" Why can't you use a left join?

Comment: I tired to use it but its return null or the not null values, and some errors.

Comment: Please post what you're tried (pared down as much as possible) and what errors/bad results you got.  Left joins can be tricky when there's multiple tables involved but it's likely the right way to get wht you want.

Comment: Please find below Query, i need to get all null and not null value even if the customer dont have nationality, Title or Gander to him\her.

Comment: FROM            dbo.ContactBase INNER JOIN
                         dbo.AccountBase ON dbo.ContactBase.new_Account = dbo.AccountBase.AccountId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SystemUserBase ON dbo.ContactBase.ModifiedBy = dbo.SystemUserBase.SystemUserId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[Yemnak Nationalities] ON

Comment: dbo.ContactBase.new_Nationality = dbo.[Yemnak Nationalities].AttributeValue INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[Yemnak Title] ON dbo.ContactBase.new_Title = dbo.[Yemnak Title].AttributeValue INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[Yemnak Gender] ON dbo.ContactBase.new_Gender = dbo.[Yemnak Gender].AttributeValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the query provided didn't had select part, so i couldn't add that part but you can change your logic a bit by taking inner join between the customer and customer relation table and then taking a left outer join between the output of the above query and nationality table. Some like this

```
    Select newValue.[columnnames] , dbo.[Yemnak Nationalities].[columnname]
    (Select *
    FROM dbo.ContactBase INNER JOIN dbo.AccountBase ON dbo.ContactBase.new_Account = dbo.AccountBase.AccountId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SystemUserBase ON dbo.ContactBase.ModifiedBy = dbo.SystemUserBase.SystemUserId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Yemnak Title] ON 
    dbo.ContactBase.new_Title = dbo.[Yemnak Title].AttributeValue 
    INNER JOIN dbo.[Yemnak Gender] 
    ON dbo.ContactBase.new_Gender = dbo.[Yemnak Gender].AttributeValue 
    ) newvalue Left Outer Join dbo.[Yemnak Nationalities] ON    
    newValue.new_Nationality = dbo.[Yemnak Nationalities].AttributeValue
```

**Note :- Since no select part was provided , i have just assumed some columns**